# Crossing on land from Cambodia to Vietnam at Ha Tien, do I need proof of onward travel?

Tags: borders, vietnam, cambodia, proof-of-onward-travel

I am thinking of going to Vietnam for a few months and maybe more...

The plan is to cross the land border [at Ha Tien](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/H%C3%A0+Ti%C3%AAn,+Kien+Giang,+Vietnam/@10.3935882,104.4866197,14z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3109da1a99bde775:0x2d2d9380034f8ca3!8m2!3d10.381909!4d104.4901728) with my family and 6-month baby from Cambodia to Vietnam, then head to Saigon. I have done visa runs at this crossing for my baby about half a year ago and they didn't ask for proof of onward travel. That time the officer just stamped our entry/exit stamps and told to move along back to Cambodia.

**Do I need proof of onward travel when crossing on land from Cambodia to Vietnam at Ha Tien?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We crossed the border yesterday and no proof of onward travel is required.

On the medical form in Vietnam, they ask where you are planning to leave the country and on what date, and also where you will stay. I have listed that it will be 'by bus' and put the same dates of entry/exit as on my visa. I didn't list where I will leave the country, nor an address where I will stay and all five of us went through a hitch.